# Java - How to locate the reason for memory leaks with jmap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

My java app encountered severe memory leaks. The max heap size is 8GB. The memory usage keeps rising and full GC is executed extremely frequently. However, no OOM is thrown.

```
     num     #instances         #bytes  class name
    ----------------------------------------------
       1:        230903     6884999664  [Ljava.lang.Object;
       2:        329559      343492320  [B
```

A `jmap -histo` shows me that 230K Object[] arrarys has used 7G memory in total. How can I find out the content of the `Object[]`, or the place where memory leaks happen?

Comment: BTW `Object[]` are more likely being allocated in ArrayList. Give their large average size I suspect your ArrayList are growing dynamically (and large ~7.5K reference each)   This places them in tenured space making cleaning them up harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the help of an internal profiling tool. Sorry that I can't share the tool with the public. The comments of this question are very helpful.

I summarized the comments below:

1) Take a heap dump and analyze it with MAT

2) Use an allocation profiler, e.g. Mission Control or async-profiler

3) Use `VisualVM` to analyse a heap dump or use Mission Control to record allocations. Note: if you reduce the TLAB size you get more fine grade samples.

4) BTW `Object[]` are more likely being allocated in `ArrayList`. Give their large average size I suspect your `ArrayList` are growing dynamically (and large ~7.5K reference each) This places them in tenured space making cleaning them up harder.

In fact, it turns out that the leak is caused by thread-local `ArrayDeque`s, each of which keeps growing its size without being properly cleared.

As @PeterLawrey points out, a large `Object[]` might indicate a growing `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` or something like. This advice is very helpful. Thanks again!